# How to find local "means" from noisy signal with Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have 2-D data from a measurement that looks as below:

[image: matlab noisy data]

The noise causes the Y data to be in the range from [4.03, 4.1]. How can I obtain a mean value (x, y) for each group of points, e.g. for the graphic this would be around (0.3, 4.07), (1.6, 4.08), (2.3, 4.05), (3, 4.07)?

I saw something about nlfilter, but most example about that represent a 2-D image. Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I generate the plot below with:

```
plot(t, y);
```

The t data looks as:

```
t(some_condition(1:40))

ans =

   1.0e-04 *

  Columns 1 through 6

    0.0216    0.0216    0.0216    0.0216    0.0216    0.0217

  Columns 7 through 12

    0.0217    0.0217    0.0217    0.0217    0.0218    0.0928

  Columns 13 through 18

    0.0928    0.0928    0.0928


  >> mean(t(some_condition))

  ans =

   1.6686e-05
```

So, I only get one value for the mean in t, while I want to have 4 means (actually, the 2 dots around 0.8) are noise too.

Comment: Which variables hold your data?

Comment: the measurement are events over time. indeed, the t (=time) and y contains both noise.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
x_filter = [0.03  0.16 0.23 0.30]*1e-5; % Insert value you want to filter here and exluce those which not

for i = 1:numel(x_filter)
    ind = abs(t-x_filter(i))<0.01e-5; % Or any other offset
    x_m = mean(t(ind));
    y_m = mean(y(ind));
    plot(x_m,y_m,'x','MarkerSize',20);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB the mean function operates column-wise, so using mean(ydata) would give you an array containing the mean for each x-position. If I got you right, here is a sample code which does what you are after (I think):

```
clear
clc

%// Generate dummy data
x = repmat(1:4,10,1);
y = rand(10,4);

My = mean(y)
```

My looks like this:

```
My =

0.5854    0.6799    0.5431    0.2933
```

Then plot the points using scatter:

```
hold on

for k = 1:size(y,2)
scatter(x(:,k),y(:,k))
markerarea = 200;
scatter(k,My(k),markerarea,'filled','d') %// Represent the mean as a diamond.
end
hold off

axis([0 5 0 1])
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Is this what you had in mind? If not please tell me I'll edit/remove my answer :)

Comment: When seeing the question correctly, also the `x` values are noisy. So some `mean(x)` might also be required. Also the date is not regular, thus it is questionable if they are stored in matrix format.

Comment: indeed, both t (= time) and y contain noise. the answer above contains some nice tricks for a scatter plot. The approach I was thinking would apply would be some kind of quantization or nlfilter but not sure.

Comment: Yes indeed Nemesis is right I misunderstood a bit the question I guess sorry about that :)